# Using kustomize on a templated manifest

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have a use case where, my deployment manifest is heavily templated.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  replicas: .{{.Replicas}}
  template:
    spec:
{{- if .optionA}}
      somethingA
{{- end }}
{{- if .optionB}}
      somethingB
{{- end }}
```

Now if I have to use kustomize, is duplication as shown below the only way to do it?

```
└── release
    ├── base
    │   ├── kustomization.yaml
    │   └── deployment.yaml
    |   └── configmap.yaml
    └── overlays
        ├── withA_withB
        └── withA_withoutB
        └── withoutA_withB
        └── withoutA_withoutB
```

Is there a better way to do this, if there are multiple options?

Comment: This is a bit of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/): what are `somethingA` and `somethingB`; are they similar or completely different? If the latter, why aren't they simply spearate Deployments? Do you need the ability to deploy all four variants? Can you implement your template as a helm chart and then [inflate that wit Kustomize](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/chart.md)?

Comment: these options are like Workload Identity, pod security policy, etc. depending upon things like kubernetes version, etc. I am trying to dynamically create the manifest.